# Qual é a diferença no uso de "reparar" e "consertar"?

Tags: significado, português-europeu, sinônimos

Tenho dúvida sobre o uso de consertar e reparar, ou se sāo empregados como sinónimos.

Comment: A depender do contexto, pode-se usar como sinônimos; ao meu ver, no entanto, reparar tem um sentido de "algo menor", mais rápido, diferente de consertar, que me passa ideia de ser algo mais trabalhoso, demorado.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

São sinônimos. Consertar tem um uso mais coloquial, reparar tem um uso em contextos mais formais, sociais, jurídicos ou militares.
Exemplos:

> *O juiz concedeu ganho de causa para a vítima e ordenou que o réu pagasse um valor a título de reparação.*
>
> *Vidraça quebrada não tem conserto, a não ser trocar o vidro.*
>
> *O encouraçado foi seriamente avariado durante o combate e necessitou ser rebocado para uma doca seca para reparos.*
>
> *Precisei ir ao mecânico para consertar o carro.*
>
> *Não há como reparar os danos emocionais causados por esse trauma.*
>
> *Colocamos uma tala para ajudar a consertar o osso.*

Como se vê nos exemplos você tende a consertar algo quebrado e reparar algo avariado.
Podemos ter uma segunda questão sobre a diferença entre quebrar e avariar.

Comment: Não sei se em português de Portugal é bem assim. E a pergunta tem essa tag.

Comment: @JorgeB. Boa observação, teremos que esperar responstas e comentários de nossos patrícios

Comment: A pergunta é sobre [tag:português-europeu]; acho que deves retirar da tua resposta todos os exemplos em português-brasileiro (2, 3, 4).